# Angular ,secondary outlet router does not work

Tags: angular-routing, angular5, angular-router

Good morning, I have a problem that has been going on for hours and I can not solve.
I have a Container component, and inside this I have buttons that should open secondary routes
the container route is as follows

```
/path1/path2/:token1/token2

    app.path.component.html
          <!-- + code !-->

          <a [routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Compose</a>

          <a [routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: { popupx: ['compose2'] } }]">Compose2</a>


        <router-outlet
        name="popup"
        (activate)='onActivate($event)'
        (deactivate)='onDeactivate($event)'></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="popupx"></router-outlet>
```

It should be noted that to access path1/*, you must be logged in, for which use an AuthGuard

```
app.routing.module.ts

      {
        path: 'compose',
        component: ComposeMessageComponent,
        outlet: 'popup'
      },
      {
        path: 'compose2',
        component: TrabajandoComponent,
        outlet: 'popupx'
      },

  {
    path: '',canActivate:[AuthGuard],loadChildren:'./home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },

  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren:'./authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule'
  },
  {
    path:'admin',
    canDeactivate:[AuthGuard],
    loadChildren:'./administration/administration.module#AdministrationModule'
  },
  {
    path:'',
    redirectTo:'/auth',
    pathMatch:"full"
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

When the application is executed, I click on one of the outlets but these are not shown

The component path to get to path1 / path2 /: token1 /: token2 is;

```
AppComponent
  <router-outlet name="primary"></router-outlet>
   <app-home>
      <app-header></app-header>
      <app-container>
         .......
          <router-outlet></router-outler>   :token1/:token2
           <app-path>
          <!-- + code !-->

          <a [routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Compose</a>

          <a [routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: { popupx: ['compose2'] } }]">Compose2</a>


        <router-outlet
        name="popup"
        (activate)='onActivate($event)'
        (deactivate)='onDeactivate($event)'></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="popupx"></router-outlet>    
          </app-path>
         .......
          ......
      </app-container>
      <app-footer><app-footer>

    </app-home>

<!-- end APPcomponent -->
```

Just like this does not work, but if I punched the secondary routes in the HomeComponent, they work, but they are out of frame

```
  AppComponent
  <router-outlet name="primary"></router-outlet>

   <app-home>
      <app-header></app-header>
      <app-container>
         .......
          <router-outlet></router-outler>   :token1/:token2
           <app-path>
          <!-- + code !-->

          <a [routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Compose</a>

          <a [routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: { popupx: ['compose2'] } }]">Compose2</a>

          </app-path>
         .......
          ......
      </app-container>
      <app-footer><app-footer>

    </app-home>
      <!-- This works -->
        <router-outlet             
        name="popup"
        (activate)='onActivate($event)'
        (deactivate)='onDeactivate($event)'></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="popupx"></router-outlet>  

<!-- end APPcomponent -->
```

If I define the secondary routes within HomeModule, they are simply not recognized, I have been working on this for hours, and I do not know what I am wrong about.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding path to the module in place of blank e.g.

```
  {
    path: 'home',canActivate:[AuthGuard],loadChildren:'./home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
```